# How to change array position based on second array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional array and I want to change array element position based on second array. I have never done this way so no idea how to do this with array. Here I am posting my array result.

**First(main) array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1201
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1200
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1196
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1193
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1191
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1145
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1144
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1139
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1135
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1053
        )
)
```

**Second array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bounced_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1193
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bounced_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1191
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bounced_id] => 26
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1200
        )
)
```

**I want this array results:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1193
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1191
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1200
        )


    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1201
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1196
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1145
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1144
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1139
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1135
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_type] => U
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1053
        )
)
```

Comment: not even a foreach attempt?

Comment: Sorry but I dont no how to do this :(

Comment: @Mr.Happy You can't get stuck as long as you don't try something!

Comment: can you post your array with code format

Comment: @User This array results I am geeting from sql result.

Comment: I don't know how you get it, but if you got it from sql result, you could sort it in sql query using `order by filed`, for example: `ORDER BY FIELD(property_id, 1193, 1191, 1200)`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be just to loop both arrays and a container. Under the loop, if your particular key matches, put the items their first that matches (sort of filtering), then after thats done, merge the rest.

```
$result = array(); // container
foreach($array2 as $k2 => $val2) {
    foreach($array1 as $k1 => $val1) {
        if($val2->property_id == $val1->property_id) { // if it matches
            $result[] = $val1; // put it inside
            unset($array2[$k2], $array1[$k1]); // remove to continue next set
            break;
        }
    }
}
$result = array_merge($result, $array1); // merge the rest
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2v0z2V)

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly - you need to find differencies between first and second, and then append that elements to second array

```
$array_diff = array_diff($first,$second);
$array_result = array_merge($second, $array_diff);
```